# macOS Catalyst App system menu issue Help is unavailable

Tags: swift, mac-catalyst, uimenu

I have a macOS Catalyst app and I am having issues with the system menu. I would like to keep the Help menu and the search bar. I would like to remove an option from the menu as I get the follow error.

When click on "App Name Help" I get message that help is unavailable. Is this because the app is not published to the App Store yet? Can I remove only this option?

```
builder.remove()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out

Create your menu items (UIActions or UICommand) to be used in the menu. Replace the help menu items using the follow

```
        // Inside AppDelegate.
        override func buildMenu(with builder: UIMenuBuilder) {
        super.buildMenu(with: builder)
        
        // Replace [] with your menu items
        builder.replaceChildren(ofMenu: .help) { _ in
            []
        }
    }
```